# Line colour of 3D curve from an array with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d, mplot3d

I want to draw a 3D line of points with different color in the Z turn.
I use the Visual Studio 2013 with Python and I have to read an .json (XML-Style) file and draw it (X,Y,Z) to a 3D Diagram.
So I got a curve with one color:
[image]
I want to have it like this:
[image]

I have a 3 dimension numpy array, but when I write this code down, like in the answer of the link, so I got an error:

> object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() (says VS2013)

my Code in short form:

```
matrix_array = [[0,0,0]]
...
-> write data in array
....
matrix_array = np.array(matrix_array)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax3d = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
N = len(matrix_array[:,2]) # Z (N now about 14689)
for i in xrange(N-2):
    ax3d.plot(matrix_array[i+2,0],matrix_array[i+2,1],matrix_array[i+2,2], color=pyplot.cm.jet(255*i/N))
```

When I take off the value 'color' so I got my blue curve, with the value 'color' I got  error:

> object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() (says VS2013).

so I read in the API of matplotlib, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example and comments in it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N = 100 # number of points
x = np.arange(N, dtype=float) # x,y,z = 1d arrays
y = x * x
z = np.random.rand(N)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# you have to plot segments, its means your arguments
# have to be a slice of arrays like here: from x(i-1) to x(i) => x[i-1:i+1]
# to get color from colormap use index: 0 <= i <= 1
for i in xrange(1,N):
    ax.plot(x[i-1:i+1], y[i-1:i+1], z[i-1:i+1], c = plt.cm.jet(1. * i / N))

plt.show()
```

[image]

In your code cycle have to be like:

```
for i in xrange(1,N):
    ax3d.plot(matrix_array[i-1:i+1,0],matrix_array[i-1:i+1,1],matrix_array[i-1:i+1,2], color=pyplot.cm.jet(1.*i/N))
```

Comment: aaaarrrggg ... That was to easy. Thank you very much for your answer.
so now my code looks like:

`for i in xrange(1,N):

        a = (1.*i/N)

        ax3d.plot(matrix_array[i-1:i+1,0],matrix_array[i-1:i+1,1],matrix_array[i-1:i+1,2], color=pyplot.cm.jet(a))`

but now my code need for 10000 Points 1 min to build the grafic.
do you now about faster way?